# Crash on DidSet from external XIB

Tags: swift, swift5, ibdesignable

I have an external `XIB` that is `@IBDesignable`.
Inside the view that shows this `XIB`, I have this outlet.

```
  @IBOutlet weak var digitizingButton: DigitizingButton! {
    didSet {
      digitizingButton.buttonIsBeingTouched = {[weak self] in
        // bla bla
      }
    }
  }
```

crash on

```
digitizingButton.buttonIsBeingTouched = {[weak self] in
```

> EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code 2)

`DigitizingButton` loads like this:

```
 required init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: decoder)
    self.loadViewFromNib()
  }

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.loadViewFromNib()
  }


  /** Loads instance from nib with the same name. */
  func loadViewFromNib() {
    let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
    let nib = UINib(nibName: .init(String(describing: type(of: self))), bundle: bundle)

    let myView = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView

    self.view = myView
    self.addSubview(myView)
  }
```

Any ideas what is going on? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the approach of your initialization.

Add an `IBOutlet` from the first view of your `xib` file to the swift file:

```
@IBOutlet var containerView: UIView!
```

Then edit your `loadViewFromBib` method as follow:

```
  func loadViewFromNib() {
    Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("DigitizingButton", owner: self, options: nil)
    addSubview(containerView)
    containerView.frame = self.bounds
    containerView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]

    // Other initialization here
  }
```